# R: sampling rows out of a huge table with row-specific probabilities

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I wish to sample rows of my table with a probability specific to each row.

My table has about 50 Million rows and I wish to sample 500,000 of those (i.e., 1%). It takes hours to do that. Do you have any idea how to make it more efficient, like using some C++ package (even though `sample` and `[` already seems to both written in C)?

The command I use so far:

```
myTableSample <- myTable[sample(1:dim(myTable)[1], 500000, prob = prob_vector),]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this would be much faster

```
ind <- sample.int(dim(myTable)[1], 500000, prob = prob_vector)
ind <- sort(ind)
myTableSample <- myTable[ind, ]
```

Before sorting you are doing completely random access. But after sorting it is much better in terms  of **cpu cache** utility.

Of course this is not yet the fastest. You can write this row subsetting in C, and it is (based on my previous experience) much faster than `[?, ]`.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed faster. I may try the subsetting in C though. Thanks a bunch!!!